# User <outlook email id> is a guest in the target AAD tenant Default Directory

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I am newbie, trying to learn Azure Devops and Azure datafactory integration. First thing i was told to do was to "Connect your organization to Azure Active Directory". I followed steps given in link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/connect-organization-to-azure-ad?view=azure-devops

It fails at step no 4. When I click on connect it fails with below error
User  is a guest in the target AAD tenant Default Directory. The current organization policy does not allow guest users to access the organization. Change the policy setting to allow external guest access and try again.

Although i made sure my user (which is the only user) in my AAD is with user type member. Why on earth it thinks it is user type guest?
I am using pay-as-you-go subscription.

Abhijeet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

•   I tried to reproduce your scenario in my environment and encountered the same issue until the point when I changed the ‘User Principal Name’ of the admin user ID to exclude the ‘#EXT#’ tag in the UPN. Since my user ID is a member of an Azure AD tenant already so it was created as an external Azure AD member in the newly created Azure AD directory.

Further, I am encountering the below error while connecting/switching to the new directory that I created.

[image: Azure DevOps Connect Directory]

Thus, the user ID/email ID that you are using to subscribe to Azure DevOps should be a member of the directory with email ID/UPN of the same directory/tenant with which it is registered. Unless you won’t be able to connect to a directory and add users to your Azure DevOps project. Also, ensure that the user ID should be an active member of the tenant/directory to be connected.

Comment: thank you for response. Yes i have gone first error now and facing another error as you mentioned in above screenshot. Sorry i didn't get the steps to get past that error. My outlook email id was registered as user in my Azure AD (default directory) but my user principle name is (<my email id '@' replaced by _ >@abhijeetmoreoutlook.onmicrosoft.com).
It doesn't allow me to change it to my original email id.  What should be UPN?

Comment: Great to know that your first issue has been resolved. You are facing the above posted issue because the signed in user ID to Azure DevOps platform is different than your Azure AD user, i.e.,<youremailid@abhijeetmoreoutlook.onmicrosoft.com>. Therefore, please sign in to the azure devops platform with this mail id and then try to connect to the azure ad directory It will be successful.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem: same outlook email for dev.azure.com and portal.azure.com but I was unable to link the first domain to the AD of the second one (User is a guest in the target AAD tenant Default Directory)

I discovered this account: https://aex.dev.azure.com/me

Try to switch the list item from "Microsoft account" to "Default directory". In my case, it worked

Rr